# What are the secret options of the PDF convert tool from OS X?

Tags: pdf, printing, file-conversion, cups

I recently discovered the `/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert` tool that is able to convert HTML, DOC, ... to PDF.

It works great but it has some optional arguments that are not documented: `-a 'name=value ...'`. I am really interested about them because these are supposed to control more of the 'printing' process.

```
/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert
Usage: convert [ options ]

Options:

  -e                   Use every filter from the PPD file
  -f filename          Set file to be converted (otherwise stdin)
  -o filename          Set file to be generated (otherwise stdout)
  -i mime/type         Set input MIME type (otherwise auto-typed)
  -j mime/type         Set output MIME type (otherwise application/pdf)
  -P filename.ppd      Set PPD file
  -a 'name=value ...'  Set option(s)
  -U username          Set username for job
  -J title             Set title
  -c copies            Set number of copies
  -u                   Remove the PPD file when finished
  -D                   Remove the input file when finished
```

Comment: LOL,  I checked the file, hoping that i may find some parameters inside the binary and I discovered that it was a symlink to `cupsfilter`. The question still stands, I want to see what options I can add when I convert HTML to PDF.

Comment: I also discovered another tool that could be more powerfull `textutil`.

Comment: NOTE: as of at least 10.14 'convert' does not exist and cupsfilter is unable to convert .docx files `cupsfilter: Unable to determine MIME type of "abc.docx"`

Comment: NOTE: textutil currently does not convert to pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options for the CUPS system are mainly for specifying borders, margins, how many pages per sheet, etc. They are documented on the CUPS website:

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html

Comment: See my own answer: The list of options documented on the CUPS website is not exhaustive. CUPS also supports almost all the IPP-defined options listed on the [IANA registry website for IPP](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipp-registrations/ipp-registrations.xhtml). Most "common" option names listed on the CUPS website map to a standard IPP option name, though.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is a symlink to `/usr/sbin/cupsfilter`.

`cupsfilter` is documented in its respective man page.

Its purpose is to allow you to *manually* run the same filtering chain CUPS would run on behalf of a given print queue would run when consuming a given input document. This way you could inspect + debug the results before/without sending the job to the actual printer.

Of course you can "abuse" the utility also to convert files to whatever output format you may desire (if supported by CUPS).

Regarding the `-o name=value` (running `cupsfilter` directly uses this syntax): basically it is every option you can specify with print command such as `lp` or `lpr` if you print from the shell.

**A few selected examples:**

```
-o media=A4                   # define the media size
-o fit-to-page=true           # request scaling of content to fit media
-o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12     # select pages to be extracted
-o number-up=4                # request multiple logical pages on physical page
-o number-up-layout=tblr      # set the sorting of logical pages
                              #   (first top-to-bottom, then left-to-right)
-o page-border=single-thick   # request page borders to be drawn
-o outputorder=reverse        # request reverse output border
```

More info about possible options:

1. All ***generic*** options supported by CUPS are documented here:
   http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.1/options.html
2. All ***printqueue specific*** options (as are escrowed in the associated PPD) can be derived from the outputs of this command:

   ```
   lpoptions -l -d <name-of-printqueue>
   ```
3. The names of all ***IPP-defined*** *(Internet Printing Protocol)* job options are listed here:
   http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipp-registrations/ipp-registrations.xhtml